# I can't find my Wi-Fi settings in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking

It was working fine till yesterday. But as I switched on my laptop today, I cannot connect to wi-fi network, also the button is gone from the panel. Please help me out.

This is what I see in my network settings:

[image: Network Settings]

Update: As suggested my @Matigo, update of uname -r : 5.8.0-38-generic

P.S: Please bear with me, I'm not much learned about the terminology of the system. Thank You.

Comment: Has your system recently updated its software? Can you update your question to include the output of `uname -r`? (You can get this by opening Terminal and typing `uname -r`)

Comment: Could that be due to turning off a wifi card with a hard switch?

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect your PC through wired connection/ethernet cable then through Software Updater you update Ubuntu. When it is done restart your machine and it should be working fine.